# Django OneToOneField default value

Tags: python, django

Recently I added an OneToOneField in django model , I set None as default value in this field . then i got this error :

**`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_myuser.album_id`**

model :

```
class MyUser(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='')
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # the default value problem is here 
    album = models.OneToOneField(Album, auto_created=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

And Here is Album Model :

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    picture_address = models.ImageField(upload_to=album_upload_destination, null=True)
    creation_year = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As **NOT NULL** constraint is getting failed hence error.

Either make `null=True`

```
album = models.OneToOneField(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Or use **signals** to connect the user with the album.

Comment: Thanks this will solve the error , how can i make a default album instead of None

Comment: You can upload a default album and pass as default to model field mostly 1.

Comment: in this way all users will have same album (for example album_id=0) , is there any way to build an instance in default ?

Comment: It will be default only when some user doesn't upload. You can make a generic.

Comment: It doesn't makes sense to use `default=1` for a one-to-one field. The first time the default is used it will work, but the second time you'll get an error because each album can only be linked to one user.

Comment: @Alasdair, I think you are right. What to do in that case?

Comment: The typical approach is to make sure that the view that creates the user creates the `album` as well and then links them, or use signals to make sure that the `album` is created.

Comment: Yeah I have used signals earlier. I will modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since:

1) all the fields on album are nullable or have default values and

2) you can pass a callable to the default arg

This should work:

```
album = models.OneToOneField(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Album.objects.create)
```

Comment: It doesn't, `Album.object` is a Manager which fetch available methods from the queryset. As the Album table doesn't exist yet, the call to create fails.

Comment: What would be a correct approach for `default` if `primary_key=True`?

Comment: Default for o2o field also requires function to return ID, you may define a function that creates album and returns it's ID